# Virtual Network and NAT set-up

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I need some help. I'm completely new to Linux. I'm trying to set
up the following scenario:

```
+-----+eth0       +-----+               +---+
| VM2 |-----------| VM1 |---------------| H |
+-----+ eth1      +-----+eth0 (NAT)     +---+
```

VM2 - Virtual machine from Virtual Box, using Ubuntu
VM1 - Virtual machine from Virtual Box, using Ubuntu: I want this to act as a NAT.
H - Host, my Windows Vista

- The dots were just added since after saving the spaces disappear.

So if I ping H from VM2, H would receive a different IP address from VM2. Could you give me a step by step on this?

All machines are of course 32 bit.

Thanks. Would appreciate the help so much.

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are trying to do? Do you mean the VMs should have an isolated network inaccessible from the host, and one VM should route out through the other?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want. What are the eth, network cards?. Can you update the question with a real picture and add more data?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you made a difficult system... I did more easyer system in the past, and I can say, that you have to use **Bridge networking mode**!!!

In VM, Settings>Network: Attached to: Bridged adapter:
[image: Bridge illustration]

Then, your modem(router, etc...)'s DHCP will give an IP for the Virtual Machine.

If I didn't understand your problem  well, please notify me via comment! :)